# Redirecting to another page using javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I want to make redirect to another page when I click in a imagebutton that is created dynamically. What I have done is a webmethod that keeps sessions save and a javascript function in page.aspx . Inside javascript function I invoke webmethod that is created in page.aspx.vb  and make redirect to the page that I want. The problem is that I cant make invoking webmethod and redirecting in the same time (inside javascript function) cause it just causes redirect without entering to the webmethod. Below I am showing what I have made:

```
 function test(id) {    
 PageMethods.takeButtonId(id);   
 window.location.href = "test.aspx" ;   
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just redirect on the server?

Comment: I have tried some ways but I can not invoke it inside web method because it cause an exception : "Thread was being aborted."

Comment: if memory serves me correctly, using `response.redirect` in ASP always throws the thread aborting exception. Can you show us the server side code you tried?

Comment: <WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function takeButtonId(ByVal id As String) As Boolean
        Try
            HttpContext.Current.Session(“btn2”) = id

          'HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com/")

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim log As New Log
            log.writeLog("test", ex)
        End Try
    End Function

Comment: I have tried as a second parameter true or false in redirect but none of them worked.